# Minimum CPU requirements for embedded Linux application

Tags: embedded, cpu, embedded-linux, yocto, openembedded

I'm maintaining an embedded Linux system based on Yocto Project. It is currently running on quite beefy hardware and I'd like to lower the cost of the hardware. So for that I'm looking for a way to understand the minimum required hardware that is necessary to run our current application. This includes RAM, flash and CPU.

RAM/flash will most likely be easy as I can check the usage with `free` and `df` commands to get a good estimate.

But then for CPU I'm unsure how to measure or calculate this data. How do I know what CPU frequency is needed? How does changing to a different ARM core affect the CPU frequency? Etc.

What would be your solution for this?

Comment: You can test some of the impacts yourself with your existing board.  The amount of available physical memory can easily be specified by a parameter in the kernel command line.  If you rebuild the boot program(s) and the kernel, you could run the SoC at a different clock frequency.  BTW your embedded system probably uses a SoC.  Cost for a SoC correlates well with package size (i.e. number of pins) and the variety of peripherals.  IOW SoC cost is not just for the processor.

Answer (score 2):

You can experiment with CPU cores and frequency.

### **Disable/Enable CPU cores:**

1. Add 'maxcpus=n' (n is number of cores you wish to activate), to the kernel command line (the bootargs from U-Boot -> during booting).

`=> setenv kernelargs maxcpus=2`

2. To disable/enable cores at kernel runtime:

- Disable core X: `echo 0 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpuX/online`
- Enable core X: `echo 1 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpuX/online`

X is core number you want to enable/disable, and can range from '1' to '(number of actual CPU cores)-1' (Core 0 is always enabled).

To see the active cores, run:
`cat /proc/cpuinfo`

### **CPU frequencies**

Governors:
There are several frequency governors which determine the frequency policy.
The default frequency governor is "ondemand", which sets the CPU frequency depending on the current system load.
(Note: the default governor is selected in the kernel defconfig. You can choose a different default governor using menuconfig before building the kernel - to reach this setting, go to: CPU Power Management -> CPU Frequency scaling -> Default CPUFreq governor)

To list all available governors:

`cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_available_governors`

To set the current governor:

`echo GOVERNOR > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor`
(GOVERNOR being one of the available governors)

To see the available CPU frequencies:
`cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_available_frequencies`

To see the current CPU frequency:
`cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq`

To see the current maximum allowed CPU frequency:
`cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq`

To set the maximum allowed CPU frequency:
`echo FREQ > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq`
(FREQ being one of the available CPU frequencies)

Use the "userspace" governor and set the CPU to a specific frequency using the following command:
`echo FREQ > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_setspeed`
(FREQ being one of the available CPU frequencies)

[Information source](https://variwiki.com/index.php?title=CPU_freq_and_num_of_cores)

Comment: Thank you, this is good advice for those where it is applicable. However, after some investigation that is not the case for me. On the board I'm having the CPU frequency is determined by the VDD_CORE input on the MCU itself, which is fixed to 1.1V. So I cannot by software alone change the cpu frequency.